# Symfony4 out of memory error upon EntityManager auto-injection

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a large project ported from symfony3 to symfony4 (version 4.0.8) with  several services (event subscribers and event listeners) that function as expected, except for one (LogActivityListener). If I disable LogActivityListener by commenting out its section in services.yaml, then everything else works perfectly. The only thing different about this service compared to others is that it auto-injects the EntityManager. I'm guessing there is something in my config files that is creating the problem, but oddly my project works perfectly with my database except for this one service.

Here is the error I see at the console when LogActivityListener is enabled:

> ## bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in /var/www/sites.clients/brcnd/var/cache/dev/ContainerXAH2ooY/getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService.php on line 24
>   PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/sites.clients/brcnd/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/OutOfMemoryException.php on line 1

My code listed below obviously doesn't do much (the real service does actual work), but it does create the above error.

// doctrine.yaml

```
parameters:
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.1.32'
        charset: utf8
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: ~
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

// services.yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\Doctrine\LogActivityListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

And my service:

```
// /src/Doctrine/LogActivityListener  
<?php
namespace App\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class LogActivityListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ['postPersist'];
    }

    /**
     * Listener attached to newly created records
     */
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't inject the EntityManager into a doctrine listener, the EntityManager  is available through the LifecycleEventArgs (eg. `$em = $args->getEntityManager();`)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!